# update() firestore CRUD modal

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material2, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

maybe someone can help me with a CRUD that I am creating with modal dialogues. I have already managed to add, delete, but I need to edit. Having said that, I have already managed to capture the data of each record in its respective modality but I can not save the changes, I get the following error: `Error: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field titulo)`. I'm working with Firestore.

[image: modal dialog not update]

**que-hacemos-admin.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

//Firestore
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

//Modal Material Design
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';


import { AgregarComponent } from '../agregar/agregar.component';
import { EditarComponent } from '../editar/editar.component';
import { EliminarComponent } from '../eliminar/eliminar.component';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/title';


export interface Servicios { titulo?: string; descripcion?: string };
export interface ServiciosId extends Servicios { id: string; };


@Component({
 selector: 'app-que-hacemos-admin',
 templateUrl: './que-hacemos-admin.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./que-hacemos-admin.component.scss']
})
export class QueHacemosAdminComponent implements OnInit {

 titulo: string;
 descripcion: string;

 servicio: Servicios;
 serviciosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Servicios>;
 serviciosObservable: Observable<Servicios[]>;
 // dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditarComponent>;

 DocPredicate: any;


 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.getQueHacemos();
 }

 getQueHacemos() {
  this.serviciosCollection = this.afs.collection('servicios', ref => ref.orderBy('titulo'));

  this.serviciosObservable = this.serviciosCollection.snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
   return arr.map(snap => {
    const data = snap.payload.doc.data() as Servicios;
    const id = snap.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
   });
  });
 };

 
 agregarModal() {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AgregarComponent, {
   width: '550px'
  } );

 };

 editarModal(servicio) {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditarComponent, {
   width: '550px',
   data: {
    titulo: servicio ? servicio.titulo :'',
    descripcion: servicio ? servicio.descripcion : '',
   }
  } );

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   if (result) {
    this.serviciosCollection.doc(servicio.id).update({
     titulo: this.titulo,
     descripcion: this.descripcion,
    });
   }
  })
 };

 eliminarModal(servicio) {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EliminarComponent, {
  } );
  
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(estado => {
   if (estado) {
    this.serviciosCollection.doc(servicio.id).delete();
   }
  })
 };



}
```

**que-hacemos-admin.component.html**

```html
<div class="my-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
 <div><h2>¿Qué hacemos? - Admin</h2></div>
 <div><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="agregarModal()">Agregar servicio</button></div>
</div>


<table class="table mb-5">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Servicio</th>
   <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let servicio of serviciosObservable | async">
   <td class="text-primary">{{ servicio.titulo }}</td>
   <td>{{ servicio.descripcion }}</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" (click)="editarModal(servicio)">Editar</button></td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" (click)="eliminarModal(servicio)">Eliminar</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**editar.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

//Firestore
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

//Modal Material Design
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';


export interface Servicios { titulo: string; descripcion: string }
export interface ServiciosId extends Servicios { id: string; }

@Component({
 selector: 'app-editar',
 templateUrl: './editar.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./editar.component.scss']
})
export class EditarComponent implements OnInit {

 titulo: string;
 descripcion: string;

 form: FormGroup;

 servicio: string;
 serviciosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Servicios>;
 serviciosObservable: Observable<Servicios[]>;

 constructor(
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  public dialog: MatDialog,
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditarComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.getQueHacemos();

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   titulo: this.data ? this.data.titulo : '',
   descripcion: this.data ? this.data.descripcion : ''
  })
 }

 getQueHacemos() {
  this.serviciosCollection = this.afs.collection('servicios', ref => ref.orderBy('titulo'));
  this.serviciosObservable = this.serviciosCollection.snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
   return arr.map(snap => {
    const data = snap.payload.doc.data() as Servicios;
    const id = snap.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
   });
  });
 }

 editar() {
  this.dialogRef.close(true)
 }


 cancelar(){
  this.dialogRef.close(false)
 }




}
```

**editar.component.html**

```html
<form action="" [formGroup]="form">
 <div class="m-2">
   <div class="text-center">
    <h4 class="mb-4">Editar Servicio</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Título del servicio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Título servicio" formControlName="titulo">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Descripción del servicio</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Descripción" formControlName="descripcion"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="text-right mt-3">
    <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="cancelar()">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editar()">Guardar cambios</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of this.titulo in que-hacemos-admin.component.ts when calling the service is undefined as you never set the value of this variable. Firestore doesn't accept undefined values. Null will be ok.

First your should return the dialog values in editar.component.ts and not just true.

```
editar() {
  this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value)
}
```

Than you have to use these values in que-hacemos-admin.component.ts when handling the dialog result. The variable result contains the values returned above in the dialog.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result) {
    this.serviciosCollection.doc(servicio.id).update({
      titulo: result.titulo,
      descripcion: result.descripcion,
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, it worked perfectly. I wonder where it is that these variables must be defined (I thought they were already defined as `string` in both components) thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I forgot to say that I just had to add `this` in `this.form.value`